# ActiveSupport::Concern official documentation question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, activesupport-concern

So I was going over the official documentation about Rails Concerns [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) and was trying to wrap my head around why their example of plain module mixin doesn't work, and how do Concerns solve this problem.

Why does the code below throw a **NoMethodError**?

Of course, I tried several approaches in the code on my end to try and comprehend the context, but I just cannot understand why the **NoMethodError** is being thrown within the `self.extended` hook in `Bar`.

```
module Foo
  def extended(base)
    base.class_eval do
      def self.method_injected_by_foo
        puts "Foo module"
      end
    end
  end
end

module Bar
  extend Foo
  def self.extended(base)
    puts "=== Acestors ==="
    puts base.ancestors # [Host, Bar, Foo, ... , Object, ...]
    puts "===== self ====="
    puts self                                           # Bar
    puts self.methods.include?(:method_injected_by_foo) # true
    puts "===== base ====="
    puts base                                           # Host
    puts base.methods.include?(:method_injected_by_foo) # false
    puts "================"
    base.method_injected_by_foo # NoMethodError
  end
end

class Host
  include Bar
end
```

To my understanding, although the `method_injected_by_foo` doesn't exist within the `Host` class per se, it should be available in the next immediate ancestor (Bar) when looking up the ancestors chain, and call that method.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.